# Trying to emulate express throws Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous

Im trying to building express with learn purpose by my own means, now Im trying to implements a express middleware system, for example, to read the client's request or serve static files, for this I need an asynchronous callback returned by another function, but when executing this callback I get writing problems after closing the stream data.

The project in which I get it has a lot of lines, so I have simulated the problem in fewer lines of code, the middleware system that I have devised is the following:

```
async function urlMatcher(url: string | undefined, method: string | undefined, routes: Array<Route>, middlewares: Array<Middleware>) {
    if (url && method) {
        const match = routes.find(route => route.path === url && route.method === method)

        if (!match) {
            response = (req, res) => {
                res.end("Route dont found")
            }
        } else {

            if (match.middleware) {
                await Promise.resolve(await match.middleware)
            } else if (middlewares.length > 0) {
                await Promise.all(middlewares.map(async middleware => (
                    await middleware(appReq, appRep)
                )))
            }

            response = match.handler;
        }
    }
}
```

In this function I check if there is a route in my routes array, a routes array would look like this:

```
const routes: Route[] = [{
         path: "/",
         method: "GET",
         handler: (req, res) => {
             res.end(`<h1>Hello first route!</h1>`)
         }
     }, {
         path: "/",
         method: "POST",
         handler: (req, res) =>{
             console.log(req.body)
             res.end("Request ended")
         }
     }]
```

Where the Route type would be defined as follows:

```
type Route = { path: string, method: string, handler: Handler, middleware?: Middleware }
type Handler = (req: Request, res: Reply) => void
type Middleware = (req: Request, res: Reply) => Promise<void> | void
```

And the response variable look like this:

```
let response: Handler
```

Then the urlMatcher function receives the following parameters through the following function:

```
function listen(port: number) {
     const server = createServer({
         IncomingMessage: Request
     })

     const routes: Route[] = [{
         path: "/",
         method: "GET",
         handler: (req, res) => {
             res.end(`<h1>Hello first route!</h1>`)
         }
     }, {
         path: "/",
         method: "POST",
         handler: (req, res) =>{
             console.log(req.body)
             res.end("Request ended")
         }
     }]

     server.on("request", async(req, res) => {
         appReq = req
         appRep = res

         await urlMatcher(req.url, req.method, routes, middlewares)
         response(appReq, appRep)
     })

     return server.listen(port)
}
```

Where the variables appReq and appRep are defined as follows:

```
let appReq: Request
let appRep: Reply
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot show here what are the types Request and Reply, I show them here:

```
class Request extends IncomingMessage {
    body: Array<string> = []
}

type Reply = ServerResponse
```

Where middlewares is an array of the middleware type that I put a little higher in this text, which looks like this:

```
let middlewares: Array<Middleware> = [
    async (req, _res) => {
        for await (const chunk of req) {
            req.body.push(chunk.toString("utf-8"))
        }
    }
]
```

In this case I have only added one that is to read the client's request.

So far so good, making requests through the browser or rest clients like ThunderClient work correctly. However, trying to benchmark with autocannon as follows:
autocannon -c 100 -d 40 -p 10 localhost:5000

It gives me the following error after making some requests:
`Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`

I have been able to verify that before throwing the exception some requests reach my server and it does not crash immediately by adding a console.log in the listen function inside the EventListener, like this:

```
server.on("request", async(req, res) => {
         console.log("New request!")
         appReq = req
         appRep = res

         await urlMatcher(req.url, req.method, routes, middlewares)
         response(appReq, appRep)
     })
```

Once everything is explained, what could be failing and how can I fix it?

I think I have provided the necessary information for my problem, however, I leave here all the code of this reduced example:

```
import { createServer, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "node:http"

class Request extends IncomingMessage {
    body: Array<string> = []
}

type Reply = ServerResponse
type Handler = (req: Request, res: Reply) => void
type Middleware = (req: Request, res: Reply) => Promise<void> | void
type Route = { path: string, method: string, handler: Handler, middleware?: Middleware }

let response: Handler
let appReq: Request
let appRep: Reply

let middlewares: Array<Middleware> = [
    async (req, _res) => {
        for await (const chunk of req) {
            req.body.push(chunk.toString("utf-8"))
        }
    }
]

async function urlMatcher(url: string | undefined, method: string | undefined, routes: Array<Route>, middlewares: Array<Middleware>) {
    if (url && method) {
        const match = routes.find(route => route.path === url && route.method === method)

        if (!match) {
            response = (req, res) => {
                res.end("Route dont found")
            }
        } else {

            if (match.middleware) {
                await Promise.resolve(match.middleware)
            } else if (middlewares.length > 0) {
                await Promise.all(middlewares.map(async middleware => (
                    await middleware(appReq, appRep)
                )))
            }

            response = match.handler;
        }
    }
}

function listen(port: number) {
    const server = createServer({
        IncomingMessage: Request
    })

    const routes: Route[] = [{
        path: "/",
        method: "GET",
        handler: (req, res) => {
            res.end(`<h1>Hello first route!</h1>`)
        }
    }, {
        path: "/",
        method: "POST",
        handler: (req, res) =>{
            console.log(req.body)
            res.end("Request ended")
        }
    }]

    server.on("request", async (req, res) => {
        console.log("New request!")
        appReq = req
        appRep = res

        await urlMatcher(req.url, req.method, routes, middlewares)
        response(appReq, appRep)
    })

    return server.listen(port)
}

listen(5000)
```

Also, as extra information I will leave the entire error message that nodejs throws:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:1009:15)
    at handler (file:///home/raxabi/****/****/****/index.ts:56:17)
    at Server.<anonymous> (file:///home/raxabi/****/****/****/index.ts:73:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.